# 'alert' is getting looped infinite times in Google Chrome but working in IE

Tags: javascript

When entering the date using the wrong date format causes an error message window to pop up indicating the error.For example, this happens when using the date "6/30/17" instead of "6/30/2017". The error message reads "Badly formatted date: 06/30/17. Use the format: mm/dd/yyyy". There is an x in the upper right corner and and a blue "OK" button on the window, presumably to close the window and allow for editing the date field. The issue is that clicking on the OK button or the x in the upper right corner does not close the window. In either case, the date field cannot be edited and application page has to be shut down and restarted.

```
function warnOnInvalidDate(s, allowNines){
    if ((allowNines == true) && (isAllNines(s)))     
    return true;
    var sObj = convertStringToDate(s);
    if (sObj == null) { 
    alert("Badly formatted date: " + s + ".  Use the format:mm/dd/yyyy");
    return false;
 }
    return true;
 }
```

Comment: no....alert comes in chrome as expected but it don't get closed.

Comment: could it be a case of an infinite loop of alerts? set the breakpoint at the first line of the function and see if it's called multiple times.

Comment: while debugging it works correctly i.e. in debug mode alert get close on click of 'Ok' button. but in normal mode alert don't get close on click of 'Ok' button.

Comment: My guess is that IE suppresses repeated alerts by default.

Answer (score 0):

Check your condition. 
By default IE suppresses repeated alerts so that an infinite loop won't occur and crush the browser.

**Microsoft never trusts developer so they implement their own code to help developers from getting into complicated situations** but they make it far more complicated in the process since finding the error cross-browser is a nightmare (yours is a live example).

```
 if ((allowNines == true) && (isAllNines(s)))     
    return true;
    var sObj = convertStringToDate(s);
    if (sObj == null) { 
    alert("Badly formatted date: " + s + ".  Use the format:mm/dd/yyyy");
    return false;
```

either your number is all nines or either the allowNines is false all the time or null/undefined for some reason.

EDIT:

*Notice the formatting of the method*

```
    function warnOnInvalidDate(s, allowNines){
        if ((allowNines == true) && (isAllNines(s))) { 
        return true;
     } else {
        var sObj = convertStringToDate(s);
        if (sObj == null) { 
        alert("Badly formatted date: " + s + ".  Use the format:mm/dd/yyyy");
        return false;
      } else {
         return true;
     } 
   }
 }
```

Comment: can u plz help me on this to get rid of infinite alerts.

Comment: Look at the formatting of my edit and see if this helps.